# Efficiently compute temporal features with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have the following .csv file :

```
Match_idx,Date,Player_1,Player_2,Player_1_wins
0,2020-01-01,p1,p2,1
1,2020-01-02,p2,p3,0
2,2020-01-03,p3,p1,1
3,2020-01-04,p4,p1,1
```

I want to compute some more columns to obtain the following output .csv file :

```
Match_idx,Date,Player_1,Player_2,Player_1_wins,Player_1_winrate,Player_2_winrate,Player_1_matches,Player_2_matches,Head_to_head
0,2020-01-01,p1,p2,1,0,0,0,0,0,''
1,2020-01-02,p2,p3,0,0,0,1,0,0,''
2,2020-01-03,p3,p1,1,1,1,1,1,0,''
3,2020-01-04,p4,p1,1,0,1/2,0,2,0,''
4,2020-01-05,p1,p3,0,1/2,2/2,3,2,'0'
5,2020-01-06,p3,p1,1,1/3,3/3,4,3,'11'
```

#### The semantic of each column :

- `Match_idx`, `Date`, `Player_1`, `Player_2` : straightforward
- `Player_1_wins` : did `Player_1` win the match ? 1 : 0

Those columns will be maintained and I want to add these ones :

- `Player_1_winrate` : number_of_wins_for_player_1_before_this_one / number_of_matches_played_by_player_1_before_this_one
- `Player_2_winrate` : same as above for player_2
- `Player_1_matches` : number_of_matches_played_by_player_1_before_this_one
- `Player_2_matches` : same as above for player_2
- `Head_to_head` : outcomes of previous matches between `Player_1` and `Player_2`. Encoded as a string of {'0' and '1'} with '1' if `Player_1` won the match, else '0'.

#### What I have done

I am using pandas library to manipulate this file. The naive approach I've been thinking of is as follow : select each match, lost or won, played by a player, and order by date. After that, for the win ratio feature, apply the two following functions to a match.

```py
def get_matches_won_before_by_player(df: pd.DataFrame, player: str, before: str):
    mask_player_won = (
        ((df['Player_1_wins'] == 1) & (df['Player_1'] == player)) | 
        ((df['Player_1_wins'] == 0) & (df['Player_2'] == player))
    )

    req = df[(df['Date'] < before) & mask_player_won]
    req.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    return req

def get_matches_played_before_by_player(df: pd.DataFrame, player: str, before: str):
    mask_player_played = (
        (df['Player_1'] == player) | 
        (df['Player_2'] == player)
    )

    req = df[(df['Date'] < before) & mask_player_played]
    req.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    return req
```

I could apply that logic to every match but this would involve to run those functions for each match, which is very very ineffective.

#### What I would like to do

How can I compute my features efficiently using only the last match of each player of a given match ? For example, updating the win rate of each player could be done with the following logic :

1. Initialize each column to 0.
2. Update win ratio as follow : (M/M+1) + (W/N+1), with `M` the current win ratio, `N` the current number of matches played and `W` = 1 if player won, else 0.

Any help or idea to organize such a process is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to operate on series so that the solution works fast. I will explain by comments in the code.

```
# to return head to head
strp1gw = ""
def get_head_to_head(s):
    global strp1gw
    strp1gw +=str(s)
    return strp1gw

(
    df = df
    .assign(
        # this is player 1 all wins before but to avoid creating extra columns I named it as Player_1_winrate to replace it with rate as you dont need cumulative sum of wins
        Player_1_winrate = lambda x: x['Player_1_wins'].cumsum(),
        # if player 1 played?
        Player_1_matches = lambda x: np.where((x['Player_1'] =='p1') | (x['Player_2'] == 'p1'),1,0)
    )
    # this is number of matches played by player 1 before this one
    .assign(Player_1_matches = lambda x: x['Player_1_matches'].cumsum())
    # the player 1 winrate
    .assign(Player_1_winrate = lambda x: x['Player_1_winrate']/x['Player_1_matches'])
    # same for player 2 but you didnt mention how to compute Player_2_wins
    .assign(
        Player_2_winrate = lambda x: x['Player_2_wins'].cumsum(),
        Player_2_matches = lambda x: np.where((x['Player_1'] =='p2') | (x['Player_2'] == 'p2'),1,0)
    )
    .assign(Player_2_matches = lambda x: x['Player_2_matches'].cumsum())
    .assign(Player_2_winrate = lambda x: x['Player_2_winrate']/x['Player_2_matches'])
    # to apply function to get head to head value
    .assign(Head_to_head=lambda x: x['Player_1_wins'].apply(lambda s: get_head_to_head(s)))
)
```